# Conditional CMAKE link to rt-library

Tags: c++, c, cmake

How to write `CMakeLists.txt` to conditionally link to the system-wide `librt` library only when on Linux environment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

cmake has several predefined variables useful for environment detection (WIN32, UNIX, APPLE, CYGWIN). Here is the full list: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#section_VariablesThatDescribetheSystem

So you can write something like

```
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(target_name rt)
endif()
```