# ROS for Windows, error LNK1104: cannot open file 'rt.lib'

Tags: windows, cmake, ros, lib

I'm trying to use **ROS for Windows** for the first time, with a package that was previously developed in Linux.
Doing the `catkin_make` I find this error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot
> open file 'rt.lib'

I think the problem is in my **CMakeLists.txt** where I have:

```
target_link_libraries(omni_state HD HDU rt ncurses ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I had a similar problem with HD.lib and HDU.lib, bacause I guess that the automatic `find_path` doesn't work well (or at all :P) in Windows. So I added

```
link_directories(path_to_lib_dir)
```

solving the problem. I would like to do the same thing for **rt**, but I can't find **rt.lib** in my PC. I also searched how to download it but I can't find a way.
Can someone help me?

Comment: On Windows there is no needs to link with `rt` library: functionality of this library is part of libc. See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695638/conditional-cmake-link-to-rt-library

Comment: Ok @Tsyvarev thank you! Do you also know something about **ncurses** ?

Comment: It is easy googled that Windows has no ncurses library. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows

Comment: I saw it, I was hoping that in 10 years something had changed :(